# iOS Swift: How to hide and reveal a button in UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I've got a run of the mill `UICollectionView` that displays a list of topics .

In the header I have 3 buttons '`filter`', '`clear`' and '`back`'

These buttons have all been created in `storyboard`, with no `IBOutlets` linked (see later). The '`filter`' and '`back`' buttons are linked to Segue/Dismiss Segue and the '`clear`' button as a `IBAction` linked to it.

The '`filter`' button brings up another `viewcontroller` (`tableview`) where a user can select various '`filters`' and when returns to `collectionview` the topics have been '`filtered`'. Works lovely.

The '`clear`' button clears any filters that have been applied to the view collection. When this is pressed all the filters are removed and the `viewcontroller` is reloaded. Works lovely again.

However I wish to hide the '`clear`' button unless a filter has been applied. At the moment the '`filter`' and '`clear`' buttons are both displayed from the outset. I'm happy for the filter button to always be present as I want users to have the ability to apply / adjust filters at all times. But I only want the '`clear`' button to be displayed if a filter has been applied. Thus, I don't want the '`clear button`' at start-up or after the '`clear`' button has been pressed...until the next filter is used.

I would normally just link a `IBOutlet` to a button, and set its `isHidden` attribute if I wanted to `hide/unhide` it at various points. However I don't seem able to do this as I get an error:

"`invalid repeating content' when I link a IBOutlet to the 'clear' button in the header`.

I tried creating a subclass `UICollectionViewCell` and creating the `IBOutlet` from there. That worked fine, I could link to the buttons (I tried combinations of lining all 3 or just the '`clear button`'. But then the segues for the '`filter`' and '`back`' buttons are no longer triggered.

Over I'm looking for a way that I can hide/unhide the 'clear' button while keeping the segue/dismiss triggers still working.

I would appreciate a poke in the right direction.

**NB**: I haven't included any code as there is nothing special about the `UICollectionView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access `UIButton` by `viewWithTag()` and than change it's `.isHidden` property. Remember to set Tag in the storyboard.

`view.viewWithTag(insertYourTagHere).isHidden = false`

In my honest opinion adding IBOutltes would be much better.

Comment: Many thanks. I used the Tag option and got it to work nicely. I agree its not very elegant in some ways, and I'm sure not best practice. If anyone can advise on a 'more correct(sic)' method using IBOutlets hen I would be very grateful